Question regarding the limit of a two-variable function $f(x,y)$ where $y$ is restricted to equal $mx$
I'm currently studying limits of multivariable functions. In this context, my textbook brings an example with the purpose of illustrating why limits of two-variable functions do not exist at points, where taking different directions results in different limits. The function they use is the following
\begin{equation}
    f(x,y)=\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2} , (x,y)\neq(0,0)
\end{equation}
In illustrating this point, they explain that if you set $y=mx$, then along each line $y=mx$ in the input plane, the value of the function will be constant, since when we substitute $y=mx$ into the function we get
\begin{equation}
    f(x,y)\bigg|_{y=mx}=\frac{2x(mx)}{x^2+(mx)^2}=\frac{2mx^2}{x^2+m^2x^2}=\frac{2m}{1+m^2}
\end{equation}
They then go on to write
\begin{equation}
    \lim_{\underset{\text{along $y=mx$}}{(x,y) \to (0,0)}}f(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\left[f(x,y)\bigg|_{y=mx}\right]=\frac{2m}{1+m^2}
\end{equation}
And therefore, depending on $m$, the limit will be different. My question is, how do I interpret this limit of a function where $y$ is constricted to be equal to $mx$?
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\left[f(x,y)\bigg|_{y=mx}\right]$$
Would it be correct to think of it as the limit of a function whose domain consists only of the points $y=mx$ on the input plane, as those points approach the limit point $(0,0)$?
I can't seem to find an answer to this question in my book or by using google.
Thank you very much for your time and help!

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, you can imagine the graph of $z=f(x,y)$ kind of give a "surface". Originally, in multivaraible limit, $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=M$ means you can go in every direction approaching to $\bf{0}$, and $f(x,y)$ will still approach to $M$.
You can regard the limit restricting to $y=mx$ is by tracing the limit by only considering the points lying on $(x,x,f(x,x))$, and considering $x\to0$. In notation, we may write it as $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}f(x,mx)$$And in general, you can consider any path, as long as you are approaching to the origin (in this case).
Note that this is a subcase of the original limit. So in case the limit exists, then no matter what direction you restricted to, you shall get the same answer. In contrapositive, if there are two directions give you different limit, then the original limit fails to exist. So in your case, since $m=1$ and $m=2$ gives different limit, the original limit fails to exist.
A $2$-dimensional (related) example is to consider the two-sided limit in one variable case. Just like in one variable, you need both left-hand limit and right-hand limit coincide to conclude the original limit exist, that's the same idea.

Thank you very much! It's really a great help!

I would recommend to graph it in this case. Functions from $\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb R$ are the best to use to get an intuitive idea about multivariable calculus. Check the definition of a limit, understand what it says visually and then try to make some algorithms to check the limit existance, value and maybe try to create some tests to check the unexistance too. It is a nice exercise and will help you "feel" what the limit is.

Thank you very much! Those are great suggestions! I will do that!
